# Using LINQ, join data from tables into single rows in multi list form view

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have a form that collects two totals for each "system type", selectable from a dropdown (I've had to obfuscate specifics of my scenario for security purposes, sorry.)

The user can add as many items as they wish. Each has an AM count and a PM count.

The form looks as follows:
[image]

The database I'm working with is structured as follows:
[image]

The schema cannot be changed.

I will need CRUD operations written in LINQ. I am struggling to come up with the "Read" syntax just to get data from the tables into the form. It needs to be limited to DySystems of Id's 5 and above.

If there was no AM/PM aspect, and simply one quantity per DySystem, I can get by with the following code I have written:

```
    public List<DySystemCountDto> GetDySystemCounts(int surveyId)
    {
        using (_context)
        {
            var joinData = _context.DySystemResourceCounts.Where(r => r.ResourceCount.SurveyId == surveyId)
                .Include(r => r.ResourceCount)
                .ToList();

            var existingCounts = joinData.Select(r => new DySystemCountDto
            {
                ResourceCountId = r.ResourceCountId,
                Quantity = r.ResourceCount.Quantity,
                DySystemId =  r.DySystemId
            }).ToList();

            return existingCounts;
        }
    }
```

To use this in the view:

```
                <tr>
                    <th>DySystem</th>
                    <th>Count</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                @{
                    for (var i = 0; i < Model.DySystemCounts.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var item = Model.DySystemCounts[i];

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <select class="form-control" asp-items="Model.DySystems" 
                                  asp-for="@Model.DySystemCounts[i].DySystemId"></select>

                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.DySystemCounts[i].ResourceCountId" />
                                <input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.DySystemCounts[i].Quantity"/>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
```

However with the AM/PM in the mix, I'm at a loss as to how I work with that.

It would be something like.. for every Am count per DySystem, also select the Pm count with the same DySystemId.

I am using a .Net Core API project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I got from your question is , you want to add AM/PM count in

```
var existingCounts = joinData.Select(r => new DySystemCountDto
            {
                ResourceCountId = r.ResourceCountId,
                Quantity = r.ResourceCount.Quantity,
                DySystemId =  r.DySystemId
            }).ToList();
```

So that your `existingCounts` should contain AM/PM as well.

```
var finalList = (from item in joinData 
                 group item by item.DySystemId into g
                 let TempAMCount = g.Where(x=>x.IsAM==true)
                                    .Select(c => c.ResourceCount.Quantity)
                 let FinalAMCount = g.First().AMCount = TempAMCount
                 let TempPMCount = g.Where(x=>x.IsAM==false)
                                    .Select(c => c.ResourceCount.Quantity)
                 let FinalAMCount = g.First().PMCount = TempPMCount
                 select g.First()
                ).ToList();
```

Not able test it at my end, but seems this will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, that does look interesting and I will certainly try it out!

Comment: Excellent, I am so grateful for that! Please note I needed to add `.FirstOrDefault()` after TempAMCount and TempPMCount on the right side for it to work, and change the last `let FinalAMCount` to `let FinalPMCount`

Comment: I also had to add AMCount and PMCount into my model - tried to add to my DTO and use that but I didn't quite get the same success.

Comment: Glad to know this worked for you and yes you need to add AMCount and PMCount to your DTO.Count will be mapped to these.